# error installing 'connect' package with npm on node.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, connect

i'm trying to install the 'connect' package for a node.js app on an aws instance running ubuntu. below is the response i'm getting. does anyone know what the problem is?

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/batch/0.5.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/batch/0.5.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-1.1.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/-/multiparty-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-1.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/-/multiparty-2.2.0.tgz
Killed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an out of memory error; try to increase memory limit temporarily, add a swap or kill a few other processes that eat memory.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I don't know what should I do. I'm a newbie `Nde.js`er. Whould you take a look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990154/installing-connect-package-with-npm-on-win-8-1 ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I don't know what should I do. I'm a newbie `Nde.js`er. Whould you take a look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990154/installing-connect-package-with-npm-on-win-8-1 ? Thanks in advance.